# How to extract class diagram from use case description from a system?

Tags: uml, class-diagram, sequence-diagram, object-diagram

http://www.iraqup.com/up/20120410/0iBvE-M60l_102420431.GIF

Here is an image for a system used in X company and the use case for it is (List Department’s Employees).  The administrator identifies the department ID number. The system displays all employees in that department.

For this question you should use a scenario based on a single department represented by an object department7 which has a number of employees represented by the objects `employee3`, `employee6`, and `employee11`) and we need to draw object diagram and a sequence diagram.

I used UML use case diagrams and what should I do to understand this from scenario

---

[The object diagram](http://www.iraqup.com/up/20120410/0iBvE-M60l_102420431.GIF)

Comment: @ lionsmaster : Since RegularEmployee can become DepartmentManager or DivisionHead, you should consider 'a  role' class. Employee has Role. The role could be DivisionHead, DepartManager etc.

Comment: it looks like homework. show something you have done.

Comment: no it's not a home work but i want the key of this software development cause i knew i't a bigining to learn jdeveloper to make projects with oracle and database( i'm learning in a self study way)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a  class diagram. What is there to extract?

The tool which allowed you to create the diagram should have source code generator. I used Enterprise Architect some time back--it was good.

Comment: not a program we should use system analyses to do this we should read the image (digram) and the scenario and draw the object diagram    thanks for your concern

Comment: This does NOT look like a Class Diagram, this looks like an Object Diagram unless `employee3` is a different class than `employee6`.